# Identifying Fitted Y, Given X Values

Tags: r, statistics, regression, glm, predict

I am fitting a Poisson GLM and want to predict y values given specific levels of the explanatory variables. My code is:

```
poisson.fit<-glm(y ~ age + gender, family= "poisson", data = data)
```

I want poisson.fit$y for a hypothetical observation of age = 50 and gender = "male". How do I produce this statistic?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `predict` function.

```
predict(poisson.fit, newdata=data.frame(age=50, gender="male"))
```

You can specify the type of response you want with `type=` "link", "response" or "terms". See `?predict.glm` for complete options and documentation.